# How do you perform a search on a 1-to-many relationship when the criteria could be on either table?

Tags: t-sql

I am using t-sql. I have what I thought would be an easy search. There is a 1-to-many relationship between SalesPerson and TradeShow. 1 salesperson could have gone to many trade shows. I need to be able to search on the SalePerson. I also need to be able to search on the LAST trade show they attended. I thought I would be able to do simple join and group on their last trade show, but I can not display the City or State.

```
SELECT     SalePersonID, FirstName, LastName, TradeShow.DateLastWent
FROM         SalesPerson INNER JOIN
(SELECT     SalePersonID, MAX(DateLastWent) AS DateLastWent
     FROM TradeShow 
 GROUP BY SalesPersonID) AS TradeShow ON SalesPerson.SalePersonID= TradeShow.SalePersonID
```

This workds, but the Tradeshow also has city and State. I need to be able to search on and display city and state. But if I include them in the subquery, I have to include thm in an aggregate function, and if I do that, I get the incorrect city and state.

The tables are simple

SALEPERSON
salespersonID PK
firstname
lastname

TRADESHOW
tradeshowID PK
datelastwent
city
state
salespersonID FK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join TradeShow  twice :

```
SELECT     SalePersonID, FirstName, LastName, TS1.DateLastWent,
  TS2.City, TS2.State 
FROM         SalesPerson INNER JOIN
 (SELECT     SalePersonID, MAX(DateLastWent) AS DateLastWent
 FROM TradeShow 
 GROUP BY SalesPersonID
 ) AS TS1 ON (SalesPerson.SalePersonID= TradeShow.SalePersonID)
INNER JOIN TradeShow TS2 ON 
 (TS2.SalePersonID = TS1.SalePersonID AND TS2.DateLastWent = TS1.DateLastWent)
WHERE TS2.City = 'CityName'
```

Comment: This will also require an extra table scan over using something with ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ~). So may be able to optimize?

Comment: Note that you're going to have issues with this if they go to two shows in a day.

Comment: I don't think it will be a table scan at all(there is a FK on SalePersonId, and I hope there is an index on this field as well - at least it is recommended to  create an index on FK columns), so in the worst case it will be index scan + lookup.

Comment: The query does require extra table scan, index scan or clustered index scan etc... that being said, this approach does saves on the cost of a sort which will likely have a higher overall cost associated with it. Would you want to MAX(SalesPersonId) as well to ensure consistant results if two dates are the same (as mentioned by Stu)?

Answer (score 1):

Re-word it: what you want is the salesperson, plus the information from the last show that they have been to.

```
Select
  SalePersonID, 
  FirstName, 
  LastName, 
  TradeShow.DateLastWent,
  TradeShow.City,
  TradeShow.State
From
  SalesPerson
  Inner Join TradeShow 
    On SalesPerson.SalePersonID = TradeShow.SalePersonID
Where
  TradeShow.TradeShowID =
    (Select Top 1 Latest.TradeShowID
     From TradeShow As Latest
     Where SalesPerson.SalePersonID = Latest.SalePersonID
     Order By Latest.DateLastWent Desc)
```

Comment: One note over the solution using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (~) is that this will require an extra full table scan when running the query, so is slightly less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a more elegant way to solve this, but my first thought is to simply grab the newest TradeShow record to join with

```
SELECT SalePersonID, FirstName, LastName, TradeShow.DateLastWent 
  FROM SalesPerson 
       INNER JOIN (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM (
                           SELECT TradeShowId, DateLastWent, City, State, SalesPersonId
                             FROM TradeShow  
                         ORDER BY datelastwent DESC
                          )
                    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
                  ) ON SalesPerson.SalesPersonId = TradeShow.SalesPersonId
```

**Edit**

Oops... been playing with Oracle too much

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by date) or SELECT TOP X
```

would be thw SQL Server way for doing this... don't have an instance of SQL-Server running, but pretty sure the syntax ends up being something like

```
SELECT SalePersonID, FirstName, LastName, TradeShow.DateLastWent  
  FROM SalesPerson  
       INNER JOIN ( 
                   SELECT TradeShowId, DateLastWent, City, State, SalesPersonId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TradeShow.SalesPersonId ORDER BY DateLastWent DESC) RowNumber
                     FROM TradeShow   
                  ) ON SalesPerson.SalesPersonId = TradeShow.SalesPersonId AN TradeShow.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: There's no RowNum in SQL Server.

Comment: @Stu - Thanks, had Oracle in my head - updated details to reflect ROW_NUMBER() OVER or TOP

Comment: Oracle in your head? Poor thing! Anyway, that should work -- in 2005 or later.